# Strange Availability Problem with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to troubleshoot an e-commerce site problem that seems to be database related. In my investigation so far, I noticed that the server seems to have an unusually high numbers relating to Aborted_clients: 65206
and Aborted_connects: 394618

This is on a server that was restarted two weeks ago.

I'm not a DBA, but I suspect that this has something to do with the issue. Can anyone fill me in on what these values mean and if it could be causing availability issues?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked [Communication Errors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/communication-errors.html) from MySQL documentation?

Answer (score 2):

From the MySQL Documentation

- [Aborted_clients](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_clients) : The number of connections that were aborted because the client died without closing the connection properly.
- [Aborted_connects](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_connects) : The number of failed attempts to connect to the MySQL server

From the look of those two status variables:

- [Aborted_clients](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_clients) : This should make you look over how your clients are disconnecting. If you connect using [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php), you should be closing using [mysqli_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php). If you are not and just let the connections die on their own, that might be one probable cause.
- [Aborted_connects](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_connects) : You should check to see what [max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) is set to. It might be too low and connections are failing simply because of reaching this max setting.
- You should raise the [**max_connect_errors**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connect_errors) and run `FLUSH HOSTS;` periodically.
- You should [investigate the other status variables related to connection errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connection_errors_xxx). You might need to get your SysAdmin involved.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know if these sorts of connection errors would effect availability? The strange thing is the the web application did not thow any errors and only four transactions were affected. Prior to this issue, the site ran fine for three weeks, so to my mind that really points the finger at the MySQL server.